# Remove duplicate from two lists without using loop?

Tags: python, list

I have two list:

```
a=['1','2','3','3','3']
b=['a','b','c','d','e']
```

these two lists have the same amount of items. I want to delete duplicate in a and for b with same index. for this example, I would like to have the result as

```
a=['1','2','3']
b=['a','b','c']
```

I am not so familiar with Python, the only way I think is to use loop

```
for item in a
   if find duplicate
   delete b with same index
```

I want to ask, is there any better way to do this, other than using loop?

Comment: Iterate it from the and and put it into a `dict()` it will do everything you want. Then use `lst1, lst2 = zip(*d.items())` to get your lists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `set` for this:

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> new_a, new_b = [], []
>>> for x, y in zip(a, b):
...     if x not in seen:
...         new_a.append(x)
...         new_b.append(y)
...         seen.add(x)
...         
>>> new_a
['1', '2', '3']
>>> new_b
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Another way to do it using [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress)(Python 2.7+ and 3.1+ only):

```
>>> from itertools import compress, tee
>>> seen = set()
>>> f1, f2 = tee(True if x not in seen and not seen.add(x) else False for x in a)
>>> list(compress(a, f1))
['1', '2', '3']
>>> list(compress(b, f2))
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use **set** for removing duplicate entries in a *list*. Please use following code to get desired output.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
a=['1','2','3','3','3']
b=['a','b','c','d','e']
a=set(a)
print list(a)
lena=len(a)
b=set(b)
b=list(b)


print b[:lena]
```

output:

```
  >>> 
 ['1', '3', '2']
 ['a', 'c', 'b']
```

Comment: That only works because all the duplicates are at the end. `['1','2','2','2','3']` wouldn't work as input, for example.

Comment: He was asking for his example. I didn't mean that it will work for other lists.I just answered for his question. Can you read the question properly?

Comment: His question was how to remove parallel duplicates from a list, not how to specifically obtain the list `['a','b','c']`. That was just an example.